# Bash shell script return first number / integer from multiline variable?

Tags: string, bash, shell, variables, format

The string may contain "N/A" at any given location, I simply need to use the first returned integer/number in the script I am working on.

example:

```
STRING="N/A"$'\n'"77"$'\n'"66"$'\n'"222"
echo "${STRING}"
echo "${STRING//[!0-9]/}"
```

returns: 7766222

desired output is: 77

this gave some useful information: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-extract-a-number-from-a-string-using-bash-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sed

```
$ sed '/^[0-9]\+$/q;d' <<< "$STRING"
77
```

Using awk

```
$ awk '/^[0-9]+$/{print;exit}' <<< "$STRING"
77
```

Comment: Thanks! if doing this from within a shell script, you can encapsulate the results to a variable: myvariable=$(sed '/^[0-9]\+$/q;d' <<< $STRING)